# Why won't my Custom React Native Component Import Correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Currently, I have a simple React Native Expo app setup. I have two components App and QRreader.

I am trying to import the QRreader component into my main App component.

The Main App component code...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, WebBrowser } from 'expo';
import QRreader from './qr';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    result: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <QRreader/>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

The QR component code...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, BarCodeScanner, Permissions } from 'expo';

export default class QRreader extends Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._requestCameraPermission();
  }

  _requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({
      hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted',
    });
  };

  _handleBarCodeRead = data => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Scan successful!',
      JSON.stringify(data)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.hasCameraPermission === null ?
          <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text> :
          this.state.hasCameraPermission === false ?
            <Text>Camera permission is not granted</Text> :
            <BarCodeScanner
              onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}
              style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }}
            />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});
```

I tried different variations of the import using "./" "." "qr.js" "qr"

Im getting an error Unable to resolve module "qr.js" Module does not exist in the main module map.

My file structure is [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zedlt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't registered your main module yet.

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('Main', () => App);` Please add this line to the bottom of your class and check if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

hmm...so it looked like I had to restart the Expo project for it to work without adding any additional code.

Just out of curiosity? 
Where would I add AppRegistry.registerComponent('Main', () => App); exactly? and why would I have to do this?